# Foiling Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I want the area surrounding 'Coffee Beans' to resemble a smooth shiny metallic foil texture. I have a mask of the area I want attached as an image texture but am unsure of how to link the nodes up to get the required result. If anyone could help, that would be great. Blend [here](https://we.tl/t-3DepLvWtAW).

*Update* New blend file added.

Sorry guys, I need to add another texture to this material. It needs to have a glossy panel on the back of the bag as shown in the mask. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite close with the nodes. I would create a material like this:

[image]

Please note that the scene you've build does note make the metal reflect so well. As every surface facing the product are white. You can create some objects in various colors to make the reflection more lively. Or you can light the scene using an [HDRI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqOXEQWRY4A) (free HDRI's including Studio HDRI's at [HDRIhaven](https://hdrihaven.com/))

Comment: Thanks, that's great. One more question though. When I set the nodes up like that my Normal map doesn't appear on the render?

Comment: Aww shoot! sorry for that, I have updated the picture in the post. Now it should be correct

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou so much. How would I change the colour of the foil if I needed to?.

Comment: No problem! I have updated the picture again. With this node setup you can just change the base color value in the principled shader.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a pro either, but wouldn't this already do the trick? Why do we need the mix shader? Edit: Oh, forgot to crank up the metallic - then it works just fine.

[image]